# Removing an item from a priority queue

Tags: python, data-structures

In Python, the [`heapq`](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html) module provides a priority queue.

It has methods for inserting and popping items.

How do you remove an item that you have inserted that is not the lowest priority from the queue?

(Alternative recipes for doing this using alternative other collections are welcome too)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `heapq` module uses standard Python lists as underlying data structure, so you can just use the standard `list` method `remove()` and `heapify()` again after this.  Note that this will need linear time though.

```
# Create example data and heapify
a = range(10)
a.reverse()
heapq.heapify(a)
print a

# remove an element and heapify again
a.remove(5)
heapq.heapify(a)
print a
```

You could improve the performance of heapifying again by using the undocumented function `heapify._siftup()`, but the whole process will still be O(n) since `list.remove()` is O(n).

Comment: But that will destroy the heap invariant?

Comment: @Will: heapify() restores the invariant.

Comment: @Will, Macke: Sorry for the confusion.  I first posted a version that did not mention you have to call `heapify()` again, but corrected it immediately.

Answer (score 6):

If you know the location of the item you wish to remove, you can do the following:

```
a[k] = a.pop()
heapq.heapify(a)
```

The first step is now O(1) time, and the second can be made O(log(N)) by using the undocumented data.  Of course, it's still O(N) to find k if you don't have it already.

Comment: You could use Python's bisect module to find k in O(log(N)) time, which would make this whole solution O(log(N)).

Comment: @javawizard Sorry, but I didn't get you as how can I find the location/index of my element in heap? I was thinking of maintaining  dict but then everytime I insert in heap I'll have to modify that dict.

Comment: be careful, a[k] = a.pop() does not work for last element in list

Comment: Sorry to resurrect this, but @javawizard, does this work? Since heapq doesn't maintain the list in sorted order, bisect would not find the appropriate index for k would it?

Answer (score 5):

This log(N) function works for me:

```
def heapq_remove(heap, index):
    """Remove item from heap"""

    # Move slot to be removed to top of heap
    while index > 0:
        up = (index + 1) / 2 - 1
        heap[index] = heap[up]
        index = up

    # Remove top of heap and restore heap property
    heapq.heappop(heap)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a data structure called a [treap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap) which is a priority queue and binary tree combined. (tree-heap). It allows for log-n search which might help you.

There's a [Python treap implementation on PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/treap/).. ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's a way which uses the internal `_siftup` and `_siftdown`. You need to use both because after the swap the element may need swim down as it may need to float up. As @rayryeng pointed out the `index` operation makes the algorithm O(n).

```
import heapq

# The removal function using internal functions
def remove_item(heap, val):
    if not heap:
        return

    try:
        i = heap.index(val)
    except ValueError:
        return

    if i < len(heap) - 1:
        heap[i] = heap[-1]

    heap.pop()
    if i < len(heap):
        heapq._siftup(heap, i)
        heapq._siftdown(heap, 0, i)


# Initial state
a = range(30)
a.reverse()
heapq.heapify(a)
print(a)

# The removal
remove_item(a, 15)
print(a)
```

Kudos to Duncan: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10163422/292502

Comment: [`list.index` is still a linear time operation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5913671/3250829) as you need to search for the index of the value to remove. Using `_siftup` and `_siftdown` is fine for removing in logarithmic time *only if you know the index of what to remove*. Searching for the index in your implementation still has a linear time complexity. The answers here do boast a linear time complexity, which is fine, but my issue with your answer is claiming this is *not* linear time. You should either edit your post to remove this assertion or modify it so the index search is *not* linear.

Answer (score 0):

had this problem on my `project` using `search algorithms`,
here is the answer:

```
queue_name = PriorityQueue()

queue_name.queue.remove(item_to_be_removed)
```

Say you had a `tuple` as an item then an example would be:

```
queue_name.queue.remove((number, item_name))
```

Comment: Question is specific to `heapq`. Are you trying to answer using Java?

Comment: @NikhilSahu no, Python, one of the above comments said that the underlying structure is like a list so I had to tinker around