# What is the most efficient way to to replace switch statement in my case?

Tags: python, performance, list, switch-statement, runtime

I needed to search and sort a huge piles of data in a biglist and put them sorted in other lists in python 3.5. 
As I finishied coding, I realized that if I only need to check for the item in biglist, I should use a switch statement to make my code more efficient. I am at beginner-level speaking of python. I searched for the switch statement in python 3.5 and was in shock that such a statement doesn' t exist in python.(I programmed a little bit in C, Java and JavaScript and they all have switch statement, so I thought that would be something that has to exist in every language for flow control.)

The part of my code to search through biglist looks currently something like this:

```
for item in biglist:
    if item == String1:
        list1.append(biglist[biglist.index(item) + 1])
        continue
   # 
   #this goes on till String10 and ends like this
   # 
    elif item == String10:
        list10.append(biglist[biglist.index(item) + 1])
        continue
    else:
        break
```

The whole program took about 12 hours to finish for one dataset. I need to do this 4 times more, but before I do so, I would love some suggestions or even solutions of how to make my code more efficient and faster, if I haven't implemented the most efficient solution already.

Please, also explain why the solution is more efficient, because I want to understand it.

Comment: Daniel has the right answer here, your problem is not the switch statement or lack thereof. Note that Python `if ... elif ... elif ...` operates much like a switch statement *anyway*. Only one branch will be picked, ever. Your repeated use of `continue` is entirely not needed. You can avoid the switch by using a mapping of lists, rather than using separate `listxx` lists. `mapping = {'string1': [.....], 'string2': [....], ...}`, then just use `mapping[item].append(biglist[index + 1])`.

Comment: I read that python dictionaries aren' t ordered and it would then mess up the affiliation between list1 to list10, so I would still need to index them wouldn' t I? For example in list1 would go names, in list2 would go emails etc.

Comment: Python dictionaries have no order, no. Did you need ordering? You could use an `OrderedDict` object, or simply sort the keys if they are orderable.

Comment: I implemented the mapping and the answer of Daniel Roseman and my program needs 17% less time now! That is a big improvment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inefficency has nothing to do with the presence or otherwise of "switch", but the fact that you use the `.index()` method, which incurs a full scan through the list to find your item. There's no need to do this, you can return an index using the `enumerate` function:

```
for index, item in enumerate(biglist):
    if item == String1:
        list1.append(biglist[index + 1])
```

Comment: In addition, using a mapping from `StringXX` to `listXX` (rather than separate variables) would let them avoid a switch altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the performance problem is not the switch-like if statements but the `biglist.index(item)` operation which runs in O(n) ([Complexity of list.index(x) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913671/running-time-of-list-indexx-in-python)).

Use something like:

```
for idx, item in enumerate(biglist):
    print idx, item
```

to keep track of the index of the item.

If you still want to replace the if statements you could use a dictionary which has a list stored for each possible item value.

Answer (score 1):

This can mimic `switch`.

```
def switch(x):
    return {
            'String1': list1,
            'String10' : list10
           }.get(x)

for item in bigList:
    try:
        switch(item).append(biglist[biglist.index(item) + 1])
    except AttributeError:
        #Do some other work
```