# Time complexity of Python's collections.deque() non-empty constructor

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity, deque

I checked the `deque` section of the [Python Time Complexity Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), but I couldn't find the ***average case*** and the ***amortized worst case*** time complexity of the *non-empty* `deque` *constructor*.

What would be the the ***average case*** and ***amortized worst case*** time complexity of the examples below?

**Example 1**

```
from collections import deque

answer = deque([[1, 4], [3, 9], [0, 2, 1], [3]])
```

**Example 2**

```
from collections import deque

def myfunc(mylist):
    res = []
    for i in mylist:
        res.append(deque(mylist))
    return res

answer = myfunc([[1, 4], [3, 9], [0, 2, 1], [3]])
```

Comment: `deque` calls `deque.extend` internally for initialization. Please refer to `extend` for time complexity.

Comment: [time-complexity-of-random-access-in-deque-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39522787/time-complexity-of-random-access-in-deque-in-python)

Comment: [Mechanic Pig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17980931) That helps; thanks!