# Benefits of using enumerate?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner at Python.
I'm wondering is enumerate a more efficient way of doing this? Or does it not matter so much here, and really only comes into play when doing more complex things?

My code without enumerate:

```
for x in thing:
    if thing.index(x) % 2 == 0:
        x += 7
        print (x)
    else:
        print (x)
```

and my code using enumerate:

```
for index,x in enumerate(thing):
    if index % 2 == 0:
        x += 7
        print (x)
    else:
        print (x)
```

Comment: You kind of answer your question yourself... **:-)** As you can see, in the first code snippet, you have to use a very inefficient function (`thing.index(x)` , which has an `O(n)` execution time as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913671/complexity-of-list-indexx-in-python) in order to get the index of `x` in the array `thing`. You do that in every single iteration of the `for` loop, whereas in the second snippet, you get the index directly.

Comment: These two codes don't do the same thing -- try `thing = [1,1]` -- and so aren't a good comparison.

Comment: That too!! @DSM is very right... In his example, `thing.index(1)` would always give `0`, since the `index` function returns the index of the first match found. Enumerate would iterate through the whole array and give you `0` and `1` in @DSM's example

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`list.index` has a complexity of `O(n)` which means you'll be traversing the list more than twice (also considering the `for` loop itself), and it returns the first index of a given item, which means you'll get incorrect results for lists with duplicate items.

`enumerate` solves this by simply generating the indices and the items on the fly; I don't think you can get more performance than what the builtin `enumerate` provides.

Also keep in mind that `enumerate` is evaluated lazily; a huge plus for large lists. On the contrary, you don't want to call the `index` method of a large list, even if there were no duplicates in the list and the results were correct, you'll still be making unnecesary traversals across the list.

Comment: And without having to loop over *just* the index and then access elements using it (which leads to a lot of annoying boilerplate).

Comment: @jpmc26 Yes, that too. When we need *both* index and item, `range(len(...))` might pass as code smell.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wondering about efficiency, there are several tools you can use to check which solution/algorithm is more efficient. This is called **profiling**.

The first aim of profiling is to test a representative system to identify what’s slow (or using too much RAM, or causing too much disk I/O or network I/O).

Profiling typically adds an overhead (10x to 100x slowdowns can be typical), and you still want your code to be used as similarly to in a real-world situation as possible. Extract a test case and isolate the piece of the system that you need to test. Preferably, it’ll have been written to be in its own set of modules already.

Basic techniques include the `%timeit` magic in IPython, `time.time(),` and a `timing decorator` (see example below). You can use these techniques to understand the behavior of statements and functions.

Then you have `cProfile` which will give you a high-level view of the problem so you can direct your attention to the critical functions.

Next, look at `line_profiler,` which will profile your chosen functions on a line-by-line basis. The result will include a count of the number of times each line is called and the percentage of time spent on each line. This is exactly the information you need to understand what’s running slowly and why.

`perf stat` helps you understand the number of instructions that are ultimately executed on a CPU and how efficiently the CPU’s caches are utilized. This allows for advanced-level tuning of matrix operations.

`heapy` can track all of the objects inside Python’s memory. This is great for hunting down strange memory leaks. If you’re working with long-running systems,
then `dowser` will interest you: it allows you to introspect live objects in a long-running process via a web browser interface.

To help you understand why your RAM usage is high, check out `memory_profiler.` It is particularly useful for tracking RAM usage over time on a labeled chart, so you can explain to colleagues (or yourself) why certain functions use more RAM than expected.

*Example: Defining a decorator to automate timing measurements*

```
from functools import wraps

def timefn(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def measure_time(*args, **kwargs):
        t1 = time.time()
        result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        t2 = time.time()
        print ("@timefn:" + fn.func_name + " took " + str(t2 - t1) + " seconds")
        return result
    return measure_time

@timefn
def your_func(var1, var2):
    ...
```

For more information, I suggest reading [High performance Python](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449361595) (Micha Gorelick; Ian Ozsvald) from which the above was sourced.