# Why is "for ... in ..." MASSIVELY slower than "list.index()"?

Tags: python, list, search

Comparing execution times of search algorithms in a list I came up to a result that `list.index()` is VERY much faster than a simple `for in`. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913671/complexity-of-list-indexx-in-python) they should be both O(n). I have this results in my tests:

The simple solution passes about 350 Tests within 3 seconds:

```
def linear_simple(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if arr[i] == #my searched value#:
            return i
```

The index solution passes all 2000 tests within 3 seconds (actually it is done even within 2 seconds):

```
def linear_index(arr):
    return arr.index( #my searched value# )
```

All test arrays are randomly generated. The tests were made several times with similar results.

That means `index()` is about 9 times faster. Why? Is `index()` not simply iterating the same way over the list like `for in`?

Comment: `list.index` is implemented and optimized in C

Comment: Big-O notation is a measure of complexity (how the execution time or space usage grows according to input size), not of the effective execution time, so the fact that two algorithm are `O(n)` doesn't mean they will take the same time to execute for the same input set.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes, I'm aware of that. But I rarely saw a 9-x difference in execution times within the same time complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Chris_Rands said, list.index is implemented in C. As it is compiled and not interpreted, code runs way faster.

Anyways, you can optimize your code a bit :

```
def linear_simple(arr, value):
    for i, e in enumerate(arr):
        if e == value:
            return i
```

This code runs faster on my computer (but not as fast as list.index)

Comment: Python is compiled to byte code executed by a VM, it's not "interpreted" (or would you describe Java as "interpreted" too ?).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers aren't both first compiled then compiled/interpreted, based on a profiler? Plus I think that he is saying that python is compiled and not interpreted

Comment: No no I was saying that python is interpreted and sure it is a bit more complex than that. With CPython https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython bytecode is interpreted and CPython is the actual reference. Anyway if python is not compiled into machine instructions (before being executed), it will be slower than optimized and compiled C functions.

Comment: @CorentinLimier if you go this route, "machine code" is also "interpreted" by the processor. The question is not "compiled vs interpreted", but compiled to what, interpreted by what, and which optimizations can be applied on the way (almost none in the case of pure Python code executed by CPython actually but that's another question). I have to ask once again: would you write that "Java is slow because it's interpreted" ?

Comment: I thought it was rethorical

Comment: @CorentinLimier this is not rethorical, your assertion is just technically wrong the way it's written. I understand that _you_ know what you meant here (and I do too), but remember that quite a lot of visitors here don't have a strong enough technical background to translate it to what you really meant.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the standard Python implementation with CPython compiles your .py files into .pyc, which then gets interpreted. I do also remember that Java works exactly this way, so since you two know what the other really meant, you can try to share this knowledge