# Change priority of items in a priority queue

Tags: algorithm, scala, data-structures, heap, priority-queue

Using Scala 2.9 to implement a kind of Dijkstra algorithm (pseudo code)

```
val queue = new PriorityQueue
queue.insert(...)
while (!queue.isEmpty) {
  val u = queue.extractMin
  queue.foreach { v =>
    if (condition(u, v))
      queue.decreaseKey(v, newPriority)
  }
}
```

I'd like to change priority of an item in Scala's `collection.mutable.PriorityQueue`.

Therefore tried to

- remove item
- change priority
- reinsert into queue.

But I can't find a method to either update priority or remove a specific item (not
necessarily head element) like `java.util.PriorityQueue#remove(Object)` as apposed in
[Removing an item from a priority queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484929/removing-an-item-from-a-priority-queue).

- How this task can be done with `scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue`
  or do I have to use `java.util.PriorityQueue` instead?
- Does anyone know whether lack of such a method is by design and it would be recommended
  to rebuild the queue after changing priority of some items (maybe take a look at discussion about [Priority queue with dynamic item priorities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288241/priority-queue-with-dynamic-item-priorities))?

Comment: I am not a Scala user, but I do know that `java.util.PriorityQueue` lacks support for decrease-key.  I believe this is because in order to efficiently support decrease-key, you need to be able to randomly access the elements of the `PriorityQueue`, something that Java's version doesn't support.

Comment: BTW, Are you sure that `PriorityQueue` is the right solution for your problem, since as I see you're not using it benefits directly and AFAIK random access operations on Queues will be O(n)?

Comment: @om-nom-nom: Do you know a replacement for `PriorityQueue` in Dijkstra like algorithms (insert, extractMin and decreaseKey are used)? And I read that random access even could be O(1) when external storing insert position of elements - but I'm afraid this is not achieved by standard impl's.

Comment: PriorityQueue will perfectly fit to extractMin-decrease-enqueueBack, I was messed up by *not necessarily head element*

Comment: @om-nom-nom: After each extractMin step there are possibly some decreaseKey's (that means some (and therefore not head) elements priority value changes (decreases)).

Answer (score 4):

Defining a case class for the PriorityQueue type to use with var for priority allows you to find it and mutate the priority. The PriorityQueue then has this new value. To get the ordering correct I had to clone it which reorders/forces the ordering. There might be a better way to do this without cloning.

```
case class Elem(var priority: Int, i: Int)

def MyOrdering = new Ordering[Elem] {
  def compare(a : Elem, b : Elem) = a.priority.compare(b.priority)
}

val pq = new scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue[Elem]()(MyOrdering)  ++ List(Elem(1,1), Elem(0,0), Elem(2,2))

pq.find(x => x.priority == 0) match {
  case Some(elem: Elem) => elem.priority = 3
  case None => println("Not found")
}

val pq2 = pq.clone
println(pq2)
println(pq2.dequeue)
println(pq2.dequeue)
println(pq2.dequeue)



:load SO.scala
Loading SO.scala...
defined class Elem
PileOrdering: java.lang.Object with Ordering[Elem]
pq: scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue[Elem] = PriorityQueue(Elem(2,2), Elem(0,0), Elem(1,1))
pq2: scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue[Elem] = PriorityQueue(Elem(3,0), Elem(2,2), Elem(1,1))
PriorityQueue(Elem(3,0), Elem(2,2), Elem(1,1))
Elem(3,0)
Elem(2,2)
Elem(1,1)
```

Comment: Actually you can bind ordering to case class like that: `case class Elem(var priority: Int, i: Int) extends Ordering[Elem] { def compare(that : Elem) = that.priority.compare(priority) }` and then simply use `new PriorityQueue[Elem](Elem(1,1), Elem(0,0), Elem(2,2))`

Comment: @Brian: If I understood you correctly, you suggest to simply build up the queue again (to re-sort) after changing priority of some elements.

Comment: @binuWADa Well, I wouldn't suggest it since it is inefficient but cloning does reorder the altered queue. I suspect there may be a better way to accomplish this without cloning the queue. If you dequeue x 3 on pq after the priority change the ordering is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Priority queues are commonly implemented with heaps. Binary heaps are [commonly implemented using arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_implementation), and if the element you want to remove is not on the path between the root of the heap and its last element in the array ordering, then there is no obvious way to remove it. I assume that this is why Scala doesn't offer removal of arbitrary elements. However, if you implement your own heap, it's easy enough to implement decrease-key for a binary (min-)heap: you just compare the new priority for a node `N` to its parent's priority, and if necessary exchange the two. Do this repeatedly until `N` is at the top or `N`'s parent has lower priority than `N` itself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with Scala but the problem I see is that a plain priority queue is not enough for Dijkstra since you need to know where a particular vertex is stored in the queue before you can do a decrease-key. In other words, a dictionary (hash table) is required to map vertex ids to indices within the heap in expected constant time. Then you get an overall O(log n) for the decrease-key. It seems unlikely to me that such a functionality can be found in a standard library. Writing a suitable class from scratch should be easy though.

The code at the end of [this lecture](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-spring-2008/recitations/recitation14.pdf) explains the idea (but in python.. sorry).

Answer (score 0):

Not a Scala user, but so far I've never seen a built-in/pre-made Heap implementation that allows for Decrease Key, because Decrease Key is only effective if you can provide (the location of) the element being DK'd.

The easiest way of getting the DK operation is to implement the Heap yourself. My method is usually to keep my Elements separate (in an unorganized array/vector/linked list) and to build a Heap of pointers-to-Elements (or array-indeces). Then, given a Heap node, you can look up the element by accessing it in the array (dereference or index-lookup). To support DK and/or Random Delete, you can add an additional variable to the Element that points to the Heap node (or keeps the index, if array-based Heap). This allows you to have O(1) access in either direction.

If your pre-made Heap comes with a DK operation that accepts a pointer to the Node, then you can simply build a Heap of self-made Node Objects, which simply wrap the Pointer in a class so you can provide comparison operators (required to build a Heap of them).

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a [class](https://gist.github.com/leonardonsantos/9650e4781483e63c20f426abea6a396b) to do exactly what you need:

- insert is `enqueue`
- extractMin is `dequeue`
- decreaseKey is `putValue`

---

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.collection.mutable.{ArrayBuffer, Map}
import scala.util.Try

class HeapedMap[K, V] (implicit ord: Ordering[V]){
  val dict = Map[K,Int]() // Keeps index of key withing vector
  val vector = ArrayBuffer[(K,V)]()

  override def toString(): String = vector.toString
  def toMap(): scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,V] = dict.mapValues(vector(_)._2).toMap
  def toSeq(): Seq[(K,V)] = vector
  def toList(): List[(K,V)] = vector.toList

  private def parent(i: Int): Int = (i - 1) / 2
  private def right(i: Int): Int = (i * 2 + 1) + 1
  private def left(i: Int): Int = (i * 2 + 1)
  private def exists(i: Int): Boolean = Try(vector(i)).isSuccess
  private def compare(x: V, y: V): Boolean = ord.lteq(x,y)
  private def swap(i: Int, j: Int): Unit = {
    val aux = vector(i)
    vector(i) = vector(j)
    dict(vector(i)._1) = i
    vector(j) = aux
    dict(vector(j)._1) = j
  }
  private def replace(i: Int, j: Int): Unit = {
    dict -= vector(i)._1
    vector(i) = vector(j)
    dict(vector(i)._1) = i
    vector.remove(j)
  }

  private def insert(key: K, value: V): Unit = {
    vector += ((key, value))
    dict(key) = vector.size - 1
    bubbleUp(vector.size - 1)
  }

  private def delete(i: Int): Unit = {
    if (vector.size == 1) {
      dict -= vector(0)._1
      vector.remove(0)
    } else {
      replace(i, vector.size - 1)
      bubbleDown(i)
    }
  }

  def isEmpty(): Boolean = vector.isEmpty

  def enqueue(key: K, value: V): Unit = {
    if (!dict.contains(key)) {
      insert(key,value)
    }
    // TODO: handle when it already contains the key
  }

  @tailrec
  private def bubbleUp(i: Int): Unit = {
    val p = parent(i)
    if ((p != i) && (!compare(vector(p)._2, vector(i)._2))) {
      swap(p, i)
      bubbleUp(p)
    }
  }

  @tailrec
  private def bubbleDown(i: Int): Unit = {
    var largest = i
    val l = left(i)
    val r = right(i)
    if ((exists(l)) && (compare(vector(l)._2, vector(largest)._2))) {
      largest = l
    }
    if ((exists(r)) && (compare(vector(r)._2, vector(largest)._2))) {
      largest = r
    }

    if (largest != i) {
      swap(i, largest)
      bubbleDown(largest)
    }
  }

  def dequeue(): Option[(K, V)] = {
    val optionRoot = vector.headOption
    if (optionRoot.isDefined) {
        delete(0)
    }
    optionRoot
  }

  def dequeueAll(): Seq[(K,V)] = {
    val resp = ArrayBuffer[(K,V)]()
    var x = dequeue
    while (x.isDefined) {
      resp += x.get
      x = dequeue
    }
    resp
  }

  def headOption(): Option[(K,V)] = vector.headOption
  def get(k: K): Option[V] = {
    dict.get(k) match {
      case Some(i) => Some(vector(i)._2)
      case None => None
    }
  }

  // change values and heapify
  // * PriorityQueue does not have this feature
  def putValue(key: K, value: V): Unit = {
    val optionOldValue = get(key)
    if (optionOldValue.isDefined) {
      val oldValue = optionOldValue.get
      val i = dict(key)
      vector(i) = (key, value)
      if (compare(value, oldValue)) {
        bubbleUp(i)
      } else {
        bubbleDown(i)
      }
    } else {
      // if key does not exist, insert it
      insert(key,value)
    }
  }

  // different from dequeue, removes an arbitrary element
  def remove(key: K): Unit = {
    if (dict.contains(key)) {
      delete(dict(key))
    }
    // TODO: handle when it does not contain the key
  }
}
```