# Scala :: PriorityQueue => update priority of specific item

Tags: scala, nonblocking, priority-queue

I have implemented routine to extract item from head, update it's priority and put it back to the queue with non-blocking approach like this (using AtomicReference)

```
def head(): Entry = {
  def takeAndUpdate(e: Entry, success: Boolean): Entry = {
    if (success) {
      return e
    }
    val oldQueue = queueReference.get()
    val newQueue = oldQueue.clone()
    val item = newQueue.dequeue().increase()
    newQueue += item
    takeAndUpdate(item.e, queueReference.compareAndSet(oldQueue, newQueue))
  }
  takeAndUpdate(null, false)
}
```

Now I need to find out arbitrary Entry in the queue, change it's priority and put it back to the queue. It seems that PriorityQueue doesn't support this, so which class I should use to accomplish desired behavior?

It's related to [Change priority of items in a priority queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103742/change-priority-of-items-in-a-priority-queue)

Comment: Have you tried using a different approach instead: e.g. a `SortedSet` (or `SortedMap`)?

Comment: @oxbow_lakes right now I'm trying to implement this with TreeSet

Comment: You did not define what `load` is above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an immutable tree map (`immutable.TreeMap`) to accomplish this. You have to find the entry you want somehow - best way to do this is to associate the part of the information (`Key`) you use to find the entry with a key, and the actual entry that you wish to return with the value in the map (call this `Entry`).

Rename `queueReference` with `treeReference`. In the part of the code where you create the collection, use `immutable.TreeMap[Key, Entry](<list of elements>)`.

Then modify the code like this:

```
def updateKey(k: Key) {
  @annotation.tailrec def update(): (Key, Entry) = {
    val oldTree = treeReference.get()
    val entry = oldTree(k)
    val newPair = modifyHoweverYouWish(k, entry)
    val newTree = (oldTree - k) + newPair
    if (treeReference.compareAndSet(oldTree, newTree)) newPair
    else update()
  }
  update()
}
```

If the `compareAndSet` fails, you have to repeat as you already do in your source. Best to use `@tailrec` as shown above, to ensure that the function is tail recursive and prevent a potential stack overflow.

Alternatively, you could use an `immutable.TreeSet` - if you know the exact reference to your `Entry` object, you can use it to remove the element via `-` as above and then add it back after calling `increase()`. The code is almost the same.